# cannot run mysql in mountain

Tags: mysql, macos

My system is Mountail Lion.

I want to change MySQL's default charset to utf8, so I copied my-huge.cnf in /usr/local/mysql/support-files to /etc/my.cnf and modified it.

However, strange things happen.

Before my copying, I can run mysql and there is mysql.sock in /tmp.

After my copying and restarting, the mysql.sock disappears so I cannot run.

I think the problem lies in my.cnf. Because whenever I remove it from /etc and restart, mysql.sock appears in /tmp and mysql can run. Whenever I copy it to /etc and restart, mysql.sock never appear.

==================== updated ====================

I found problem lies in the statement:

> default-character-set = utf8

which I added in my.cnf under [mysqld]

when I detele it, mysql can restart and run.

==================== problem solved ====================

I should use

```
character-set-server = utf8
```

instead.
......I don't know why default-character-set = utf8 doesn't. Every tutorial on the internet uses it. =.=

Comment: Check the owner/group/permissions of my.cnf. Failing that you may want to check on the extended attributes (see [xattr(1)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html)).

Comment: "Sometimes" (actually **always**) it makes much more sense to read official documentation not some terrible articles from newbies: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-configuration.html http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_character-set-server